# Mysql how to create EQUAL constraint?

Tags: mysql, triggers, constraints, unique-constraint, check-constraints

Is there a way to create an "EQUAL" constraint in Mysql?

Imagine I have a table like this

```
tb_1:

id | id_fk | order | id_tb_2 | Column D
----------------------------------------
1  | 1     | 1     | 10      | AAA
2  | 1     | 2     | 20      | BBB
3  | 2     | 1     | 30      | CCC
4  | 3     | 1     | 40      | DDD
```

And:

```
tb_2:

id_tb_2 | id_type
------------------
10      | 100
20      | 200
30      | 300
40      | 400
```

And:

```
tb_3:

id_type | model    | other_prop
--------------------------------
100     | model_A  | A
200     | model_A  | B
300     | model_B  | C
400     | model_C  | D
```

I want to make sure that `tb_2.id_type.model` are going to be equal for same values of `id_fk` and different `order`.

So I have a `UNIQUE` constraint for `[id_fk, order]`

And I need a `EQUAL` constraint for `[id_fk, id_tb_2.id_type.model]`

This way, I shouldn't be able to create a value in `tb_1` like:

```
id | id_fk | order | id_tb_2 | Column D
----------------------------------------
1  | 1     | 1     | 10      | AAA
2  | 1     | 2     | 20      | BBB
5  | 1     | 3     | 30      | EEE  <--- This has a different model in tb_2
```

How can I create one?

Comment: CHECK constraint in MySQL can check one record only (subqueries, including implicit, are not allowed). So only trigger checking logic may solve this tak.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using proper relational normalization is to drop the `tb_1.Column D` column.

Then the reference to `tb_2.id_tb_2` and by extension to `tb_3.id_type` will be unambiguous.

```
tb_1:

id | id_fk | order | id_tb_2
----------------------------
1  | 1     | 1     | 10
2  | 1     | 2     | 20
3  | 2     | 1     | 30
4  | 3     | 1     | 40
```

In other words, by including Column D in tb_1, you're violating [Third Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), because Column D is an attribute that depends on something other than the primary key of tb_1.

But I'm not sure you've told us the full scope of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was a bit off. I updated it to be more consistent with the complexities my case demands.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer given your new description.

Comment: Maybe I'm simplifying too much. I'll explain my problem here. The question is what I tried to do already. Maybe it's wrong all the way up.

Comment: I have an entity Types of Maps. The Types have properties like Origin and Grid. One Type should have only one Grid. One Type may have many Origins. The Types have a priority for which Origin the data comes from. That's why I tried the order column. What I need to ensure is that, if the Types has more than one Origin, than, it has to be the same Grid as the first. In summary, I need to implement an array of Origins. I can't simply use many rows with Grid and Origins, because some Origins have some Grids, but not all of them, so I need another table referencing which Origin has which Grid.

Comment: Okay I am not going to spend the time to understand that description to see if it matches your original problem described above. I have a suspicion that you're revealing new information about your task each time you explain it, so I have no idea how much more information is coming. This makes it impossible to answer. I'll wish you good luck, and bow out of the conversation now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The only constraints that relate data from multiple tables are `FOREIGN KEY` constraints; and they are very limited about the relationship they check: a list of columns against another list of columns on another/same table.

All other relational constraints (such as `UNIQUE` or `CHECK`) have a table scope.